# Rails 4.2 rendering JSON formatting DateTime weirdly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that is rendering JSON. Specifically all the `ticket`s associated with a specific `show`. So when a user attempts to reserve a `ticket`, the `ticket` is reserved, and then a list of all `ticket`s as JSON is sent back to the user's browser to render with some JavaScript.

I am running into some weird output though, if I create a `show` and give it 2 `ticket`s, then call `ticket.show.tickets.as_json` I get the following `Array`:

```
{"show_id"=>1, "id"=>1, "user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:47:44 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:47:44 UTC +00:00, "status"=>"open", "reserved_until"=>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:57:44 UTC +00:00, "seat_id"=>1}
{"show_id"=>1, "id"=>2, "user_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:47:44 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Wed, 22 Apr 2015 21:47:44 UTC +00:00, "status"=>"open", "reserved_until"=>nil, "seat_id"=>2}
```

But if I run the following code in my controller, this is the `Array` I get:

```
{"show_id"=>1, "id"=>1, "user_id"=>1, "created_at"=>"2015-04-22T21:47:44.338Z", "updated_at"=>"2015-04-22T21:47:44.345Z", "status"=>"open", "reserved_until"=>"2015-04-22T21:57:44.343Z", "seat_id"=>1}, {"show_id"=>1, "id"=>2, "user_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2015-04-22T21:47:44.340Z", "updated_at"=>"2015-04-22T21:47:44.340Z", "status"=>"open", "reserved_until"=>nil, "seat_id"=>2}
```

TicketsController:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  def reserve
    begin
      @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    rescue
      return
    end
    @ticket.reserve_ticket current_or_guest_user

    render json: @ticket.show.tickets
  end
end
```

I tried calling `render json: @ticket.show.tickets.as_json` in the controller, but I got the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're expecting `as_json` to return the object as json. This is a not at all unreasonable expectation! Unfortunately, [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) returns "a hash representing the model". It is a configurable way of returning a hash which can then easily be turned into json with `to_json`.

Your `render json: ...` call will actually invoke that `to_json` for you which means that you get actual json. With just an `as_json` call you get mappings from model attributes to values but those values themselves are not converted to json.

Answer (score 0):

When you render json it will try to call to string for all attributes and that's why you see it that way:

```
:004 > DateTime.now
 => Thu, 23 Apr 2015 00:20:29 +0200 
:005 > DateTime.now.to_s
 => "2015-04-23T00:20:33+02:00"
```

You can override as json in your model and customize dates string format:

```
:006 > DateTime.now.strftime("%d %b %y at %I %p")
 => "23 Apr 15 at 12 AM"
```

so in your model:

```
def as_json(options={})
  {       
    created_at: self.created_at.strftime("%d %b %y at %I %p"),
    show_id: self.show_id,
    user_id: self.user_id,
    id: self.id
  }
end
```